# How can I see printf output when evaluating an expression using the `expr` command in lldb?

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb

Let us say that I have a function in a C program `test.c` like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
char* foo = "test";
void print_foo(void)
{
    printf("%s", foo);
}
main() {  }
```

I compile and run `test.c` like this:

```
gcc -g -o test test.c
chmod 755 test && lldb -s <(echo "b main\nr") test
```

However, if I then run `expr print_foo()` no string output occurs:

```
(lldb) expr print_foo()
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STDOUT` is line buffered.  You haven't emitted a newline yet.  Try:

```
(lldb) expr (void) fflush(0)
```

and you should see the output.  Or have foo be `"test\n"`.