# lldb - printf / nslog on Xcode Console vs macOS Terminal

Tags: printf, stdout, lldb

On a real device, running an iOS app, via Xcode the following lldb commands output to the Xcode console as expected:

```
(lldb) exp (void)NSLog(@"hello from NSLog");
(lldb) exp (int)printf("hello from printf");
```

On a real device + `Terminal`, these commands send no output to the screen.  Even if you flush the screen (as recommended here: [How can I see printf output when evaluating an expression using the `expr` command in lldb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969943/how-can-i-see-printf-output-when-evaluating-an-expression-using-the-expr-comma_)).

Am I missing a lldb `settings` command or environment variable?

That said, on a real iOS device + Terminal you can still use the python-lldb scripting commands:

```
(lldb) script print("hello")
hello
```

PS - I tried with both `zsh` and a default `bash` terminal.

Comment: How are you launching the process in the "iOS device + Terminal" case?  If you are finger launching and then attaching, stdout is already diverted to the Console log, and lldb can't see it.

Comment: Ah hah! I can see NSLog message in Console.app.  When launching lldb I tried `process attach --pid 123`, `-waitfor my_app` and then specifying `LLDB_SDK=ios lldb....` and `settings set target.env-vars DEBUG=1`

Comment: Since you are attaching, this is the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106019/xcode-attach-to-process-doesnt-display-nslog

Comment: @JimIngham  is there a way to launch lldb to receive stdout ?  Otherwise I have to open console.app on macOS to check whether my expression statements have worked.

Comment: lldb has options to control where stdout goes when it is the one that launches the process.  But when you attach, stdout is already hooked up somewhere else.  There isn't a really good way to divert stdout mid-run.  So if you can use Xcode to launch the process this should just work.  If you have to attach to an already running process, there isn't a good way to do this.